# Block a device from connecting to a specifix router

Tags: wifi-direct

There is an ISP in my town that connects to my phone all the time, but it wants to sign in to be used. It is not my ISP so that all I get is my Wi-Fi blocked.

There are many spots from the same ISP in town, because a couple of ISP give their customer a router with two Wi-Fi outputs, one private, normal, and another one open for their customers use with their site password wherever they exist. One of them (not my ISP) sticks to the devices, so I get blocked in many areas.

I have tried to change *autojoin=1* to *autojoin=0* on `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`, but that didn't do anything. This file also mentions another one, `ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets`. Will that control I need be here?

I am almost sure there will be a way to disallow a device from connecting to a specific Wi-Fi, but I don't know how. Maybe somebody can help me and teach me how, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Settings and choose the option to Reset Network Data, this will erase the phone's memory of ever connecting to the many millions of these open wifi hotspots that are around. Then just go into Wifi settings and toggle the switch to "disabled" on the option that says "Automatically connect to high quality public networks" and you'll be good to go. I personally do this and it seems to yield results.

OR

If you have root access you can try the following:

1. Install Termux from Play Store (not some other terminal emulator, must be Termux)
2. Type `apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install nano tsu -y`
3. Become root via `tsu`
4. Turn off Wi-Fi
5. Now you'll be editing a file, which will require the use of arrow keys, theres another app called Hacker Keyboard that has arrow keys you can use. This file may be called something else on older versions of Android, so YMMV.
6. Type `nano /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`
7. The file contains history of all previously connected Wifi networks. The XML is structured by , so you'll need to scroll through and find the network you don't want your phone connecting to anymore. It will be preceded by a  tag, and will also contain several other  inside of it; just continue scrolling until you find the VERY next occurrence of , signifying the entire configuration for the unwanted network.
8. Erase the unwanted network configuration by deleting everything from  to , ensuring that you are only removing the configuration for specifically unwanted network.
9. Now just do a `Ctrl+O`, `[Enter]`, `Ctrl+X` to save, confirm, then exit the file.
10. Type `chown $(whoami) /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml` to change the owner to root
11. Type `chmod 640 /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml` to allow the group member (`System`) to still have read access to be able to retain normal functionality, but disallow write access to be able to re-write the unwanted wifi configuration back into WifiConfigStore.xml.

Please note that this will mean you can no longer save any additional wifi networks to be automatically connected, and your device will only remember the networks that you left in the file before running steps 10 & 11. If you ever want to revert the changes and re-allow typical access to the file just undo steps 10 & 11 via the following:

1. Open `adb shell` or Termux again
2. Gain root via `su` (if adb shell), or `tsu` (if Termux)
3. Type `chown system /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`
4. Type `chmod 600 /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`

Cheers

Comment: It is possible to be the same ISP you mention, but as you know, bad intentions often spread quickly over the world, and some commercial fight like this can be extremely annoying,.

Comment: Well I only know of the one and only that has all of the features mentioned, but you're right, there could be more I'm unaware of. Lmk if this fixes your issue or not, and I'll see if I can come up with something else for you.

Comment: I don't have exactly the same text as you tell me: "Automatically connect to high quality public networks". The most similar I have is in the Advanced options (Wi-Fi settings) titled Passpoint  "Automatically connect to Passpoint-certified Wi-Fi access points". I unmarked the case.<br/>
However, I can tell you that it still connects immediately to my home router when the Wi-Fi is turned on, but I can't try about the problem right away because I'll have to go out to walk around, and the weather is very bad. I will have to wait for tomorrow. I'll be back and post the result here for you.

Comment: Well, I am not on any ≥7 Android OS, but maybe you can kindly tell me how to do it by hand. Because it has to be in some OS file, and if you hate it as much as I do, you probably used to do it much before Android 7. Thanks.

Comment: Before starting anything, I made sure that I had all the “ingredients”, and I found a problem. I don’t have any file named WifiConfigStore.xml and there is not any .xlm file at either that address or at /system/etc/wifi/. After checking this, I searched for .xml files with ES File Explorer, but there are hundreds of them, I believe over a thousand. I will look for any name that might correspond with its function, and it might help if you could give an idea of its content, like posting a copy here.<br/>
These text boxes are too small.

Comment: It looks like it is going to take me some time pocking the system. Thank you for your patience. I’ll be back when I have news.

Comment: I am very disappointed; I could not find any XLM file with a name that triggered my mind and over 2.5 KB, what I actually supposed to be much less than the minimum size necessary for that file. How can I find the name of the file, and what else can I do, please?

Comment: As I said, I can’t follow your instructions because I don’t have that .xml file or else it has another name, but I had done what I wrote on my third comment. That is, on the advanced settings I unmarked that case for "Automatically connect to Passpoint-certified Wi-Fi access points". </br>
Today, I went around for over one hour and that ISP hotspots did not connect as they have been insistently doing, but don't think it is very conclusive. I will to try again and for a longer time. </br>
Do you think you can give me some tips that might help finding that .xml file? Thanks.

Comment: therealjayvi, during these past days that ISP hotspots that are very often there at shirt distance, as usually, did not connect again. The only thing I did since I opened this thread was trying to follow your advice to  disable the advanced settings option that says "Automatically connect to high quality public networks".

Comment: As I don't have that, but one with a similar text, "Passpoint "Automatically connect to Passpoint-certified Wi-Fi access points"", I clearer that case. Passpoint is a technology for connecting hotspots. Therefore, I presume that ISP is using it and so it worked, even if it should not use it because thereafter it wants a "hard" login. That way, it is useful for their customers, but it is a very bothering abuse for anyone else. Thank for your help.